# how can I fixed the carousel-caption in bootstrap4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have some images for carousel and a nav-tab. I want to use this nav-tab on the carousel. and when the carousel image change , carousel caption fixed. how can I fix the carousel caption on the carousel? or is there any way to fix nav-tab on the carousel?
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you need to put caption outside the carousel and place it using position..
as

```
<div class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner"></div>
  <div class="caption">
        <h3>My Cap</h3>
        <p>We had such a great time in LA!</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok thank you, but how can I fixed the caption? i used position:fixed; in css but it didn't work. do you have any suggestion?

Comment: make carousel as position relative then caption as position absolute, left:50% and bottom:60px enough;